# counting frequency of integers take together

Tags: c++

I need to count the frequencies of different integers together in a binary file, how can I do this? I do not wish to convert to string, because that would slow down my program down.. I think...

```
vector<uint32_t> buf(2);
map<uint32_t, uint32_t> mymap;

if(file.is_open())
{
    while (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&buf[0]), sizeof(uint32_t)*numcols))
    {
        for(size_t i = 0; i < numcols; ++i)
        {
            mymap[buf[i]]++; // **---> I need help here**
        }
    }
}
file.close();
```

How can I make the key to the map so that it always counts those integers together

Yep.. how many times I see integer pairs consecutively, like how many times (1,2), or (8, 14), or (7,3).

```
1 2
1 2
7 3
8 14
8 14
8 14

1 2 --> 2 times
7 3 --> 1 time
8 14 --> 3 times
```

numcols == 2 correct.

Comment: I assume that `numcols == 2`?

Comment: Also, can you clarify exactly what it is that you're trying to do?  That is, can you be a bit clearer about what all of these objects are?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to count how many times you see each pair of integers consecutively? Do you want overlapping pairs? I.e. if the file contains the numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, then are you also counting the pair (2, 3), or just (1, 2) and (3, 4)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option might be to have the `map` use `pair<uint32_t, uint32_t>`s as keys.  That way you're explicitly mapping from pairs of `uint32_t`s to the frequency with which they appear.

Comment: what if I wanted to scale this to triplets, quadruplets etc...
something like frequencies of (1,2,3,4) and (3,8,7,1)?

Comment: You might want to look into boost::tuple as a generalization of std::pair.  It's going to be in the new C++ standard, and if you're using the right compiler you should just get it for free.