# What data structure is the quickest for inserting and searching for elements?

Tags: c++

I am writing a program that will do a basic compression using a lookup table. To create the table, I will read in a text file (size 2MB) and then find the 255 most common words and store them into another text file. I am trying to use a vector now, but the runtime is slow at about a minute of runtime to insert into the vector, sort it, and then output the top 255 elements to another text file. The insertion appears to be the problematic since I am having to check for whether or not it already exists inside of the vector and then increment a counter if it does exist, or add the element to the end of the vector if it doesn't. I need to find an efficient way of inserting elements into a data structure only when they are not already inside of the data structure (No Duplicates).

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4687392/counting-frequency-of-integers-take-together , http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322031/extending-a-program-to-count-line-frequency?rq=1 for the general "solution" to this problem of counting frequencies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`std::unordered_map` is *likely* to be the best for your purpose, no guarantees. You can "add a key if and only if not already present" just by using `operator[]`.

You'll make one pass over the 2MB splitting into words and counting the frequencies (one lookup in the structure per word). Then use `std::partial_sort_copy` (the version that takes a comparator) to get the top 255 by frequency count from the `unordered_map`. You should `partial_sort_copy` into a vector or array and then use that to write the file.

For 2 MB of data, anything over a few seconds is certainly slower than it "should" be, and a few seconds is still slower than it could be. So you're right to be concerned about your vector, but you should also profile your code to make sure that it really is the vector costing you the time, not some other issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using STL `map` or `set` it is much faster than vector: see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985572/which-is-the-fastest-stl-container-for-find)

Comment: The code should use a `map` as the frequencies must be stored as well. Also, "much faster" needs to be qualified as they are fundamentally different data structures.